# What's the cell structure of K(Z/nZ, 1)?  Does it let me sum this divergent series?  What about other finite groups?

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, divergent-series, euler-characteristics

The Eilenberg-Maclane space $K(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}, 1)$ has a particularly simple cell structure: it has exactly one cell of each dimension.  This means that its "Euler characteristic" should be equal to
$$1 - 1 + 1 - 1 \pm ...,$$
or Grandi's series.  Now, we "know" (for example by analytic continuation) that this sum is morally equal to $\frac{1}{2}$.  One way to see this is to think of $K(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}, 1)$ as infinite projective space, e.g. the quotient of the infinite sphere $S^{\infty}$ by antipodes.  Since $S^{\infty}$ is contractible, the "orbifold Euler characteristic" of the quotient by the action of a group of order two should be $\frac{1}{2}$.

More generally, following John Baez $K(G, 1)$ for a finite group $G$ should be "the same" (I'm really unclear about what notion of sameness is being used here) as $G$ thought of as a one-object category, which has groupoid cardinality $\frac{1}{|G|}$.  In particular, $K(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}, 1)$ should have groupoid cardinality $\frac{1}{n}$.  I suspect that $K(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}, 1)$ has $1, n-1, (n-1)^2, ...$ cells of each dimension, hence orbifold Euler characteristic

$$\frac{1}{n} = 1 - (n-1) + (n-1)^2 \mp ....$$
Unfortunately, I don't actually know how to construct Eilenberg-Maclane spaces...

**Question 1a:**  How do I construct $K(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}, 1)$, and does it have the cell structure I think it has?  (I've been told that one can write down the cell structure of $K(G, 1)$ for a finitely presented group $G$ explicitly, but I would really appreciate a reference for this construction.)

**Question 2:**  $K(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}, 1)$ turns out to be "the same" as the set of all finite subsets of $(0, 1)$, suitably interpreted; the finite subsets of size $n$ form the cell of dimension $n$.  Jim Propp and other people who think about combinatorial Euler characteristic would write this as $\chi(2^{(0, 1)}) = 2^{\chi(0, 1)}$.  Is it true more generally that $K(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}, 1)$ is "the same" as the set of all functions $(0, 1) \to [n]$, suitably interpreted?

**Question 3:**  What notion of "sameness" makes the above things I said actually true?

**Question 4:**  Let $G$ be a finite group and let $K(G, 1)$ be constructed using the standard construction I asked about in Question 1.  If $c_n$ denotes the number of cells of dimension $n$, let $f_G(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} c_n z^n$.  Can $f_G$ always be analytically continued to $z = -1$ so that $f_G(-1) = \frac{1}{|G|}$?

Comment: It's the infinite lens space.  I believe it's in Hatcher's book.  The cell structure you build inductively just like with real projective space. 

Q2, see this recent thread: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/2900/how-to-get-product-on-cohomology-using-the-kg-n/19706#19706

Q3: see the linked thread. 

Comment: For the lens space, see Hatcher, Example 2.43.

Comment: Hum, you're right; I should've checked Hatcher more thoroughly before asking this question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are multiple possible cell structures on K(Z/n,1).

One is generic.  For any finite group G there is a model for BG that has (|G|-1)<sup>k</sup> new simplices in each nonzero degree k.  This is the standard simplicial bar construction of K(G,1).  This gives you that BG has Euler characteristic 1/|G|, if you like.

One is more specific.  There is another cell structure on K(Z/n,1), viewing it as a union of generalized lens spaces, that has exactly one cell in each degree.  This is a topological avatar of the "simple" resolution of Z by free Z[Z/n]-modules.  Obviously this doesn't give you the Euler characteristic argument you're seeking - one needs to keep track of more intricate information about the cell attachments in order to extract something.

Answer (score 11):

The answer to something like question 4 is "yes".  It not only has an analytic continuation to $-1$, it has a *unique* such.  In fact, it's a rational function.  Something similar is true not only for finite groups but for "most" finite categories.  See [this paper](http://intlpress.com/HHA/v10/n1/a3/), especially Example 2.4.

(I say "*something like* question 4" because I'm taking $c_n$ to be the number of nondegenerate $n$-simplices in the nerve of $G$, which I think isn't quite what you have in mind.)